# Angular Js + Youtube embed is not rending with ng-bing-html using ng-sanitize, how to resolve?

Tags: angularjs

I am attempting to render Youtube videos along with content. The content renders however the embedded Youtube video is not. I read that I need to white list youtube for rending but I think my setup needs adjustment. My content comes through in a ng-repeat like such:

**ng-bind-html=activity.content**

```
Here is a song to listen to:
<iframe width="560" height="315" ng-src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/dcdgV0eYLSQ" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

template looks like such

```
<div class="activity" ng-bind-html="activity.content"></div>
```

I tried setting a whitelist url to the $sceDelegateProvider but I think I am missing a step. How do I make sure that youtube is accepted? It currently isn't.

```
app.config(function($sceDelegateProvider) {
    $sceDelegateProvider.resourceUrlWhitelist([
        'self',
        '*://www.youtube.com/**'
    ]);
});
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly with 'the content renders but the embedded Youtube video is not?' Do you get any errors in Console?

Comment: The template tag contains both an embedded Youtube video and a string of text. The string of text displays but the Youtube video does not.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a filter that returns the function to trust that resource.

```
.filter('trustAsResourceUrl', ['$sce', function($sce) {
         return function(val) {
             return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(val);
         };
}]);
```

And then apply it to your binding like this

```
 <div class="activity">
        <iframe ng-src="{{embed | trustAsResourceUrl}}" width="560" height="315" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
 </div>
```

[Working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/bZh4xq4cgRgcp2zV)